# Draw chart based on dropdown selection in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, highcharts, handlebars.js

I am trying to draw a chart when the user selects a different option in a dropdown by using Backbone.js, Highchart and handlebars. I have used collection to store JSON values and used toJSON function to display all the values in dropdown and to draw a chart. Everything is working perfectly like drawing Chart and display values in dropdown.

Now i am trying to draw first two values(two bars) only while page load. After that the first value/bar will be a constant it needs not to draw a chart and second bar charts have to be drawn based on the dropdown selection. For example if the user select Edvin need to draw chart for the Edvin user and so on.

To achieve, i have used "select" backbone event. I am calling "tableModified" function when the dropdown value is changed. Then i am checking if the value is matched with collection value again i am calling "modifyTableValue" function. The above "tableModified" function is getting fired when i change any values in dropdown and also i can see the selected dropdown valued in console.

Here i am trying to display first two bar charts after that need to draw a chart based on selection in the dropdown.

Here is my backbone JS code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        callSer(".clg-chart");
    });

    // Backbone Model
    var ClgModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    // Backbone Collection
    var ClgCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ClgModel
    });
    loadFromJson = function (input) {

        if (_.isArray(input)) {
            var collection = new ClgCollection();

            _.each(input, function (data) {
                var a = collection.length;
                collection.add(loadFromJson(data));
            });
            return collection;
        }

        return new ClgModel({
            ClgName: input.Name,
            ClgRates: input.Rate
        });
    };
    // Backbone View
    var ClgView = Backbone.View.extend({
        collection: ClgCollection,
        events: {
            "change select.clgchart-selection": "tableModified"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            //        console.log("initialize fun");
        },
        render: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.collection.each(function (clgTableModel) {
                if (clgTableModel.get("selectedSnapshot")) {
                    that.modifyTableValue(clgTableModel);
                }
            });
            var rates = new Array();
            var categories = new Array();
            var series = new Array();
            var data = new Array();
            var colors = ['#045DSD', '#997779', '#997779', '#997779', '#997779'];
            var chartHeight = this.collection.length * 70;
            this.$el.find('.chartcalc .chart-fade').height(chartHeight);
            var labelColor = [];
            this.collection.each(function (model, i) {
                categories.push(model.get("ClgName"));
                rates.push(model.get("ClgRates"));
                dataObject = new Object();
                dataObject.y = rates[i];
                dataObject.color = colors[i];
                data.push(dataObject);
                seriesObject = new Object();
                seriesObject.borderWidth = 0;
                seriesObject.name = categories[i];
                seriesObject.data = rates[i];
                seriesObject.shadow = false;
                series.push(seriesObject);

                if (true) {
                    // #RE# To draw right side chart bar
                    if (i === 0) {
                        that.$el.find('.clgchart-labels').append('<tr><td>' + categories[i] + '</td></tr>');
                    } else {
                        that.$el.find('.clgchart-labels').append('<tr><td>' + categories[i] + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                }
                console.log("categories:" + categories[i]);
                console.log("rates:" + rates[i]);
            });

            var renderToElement = this.$el.find(".chart-clg")[0];
            if (true) {
                // #RE# To draw left chart section
                this.initChartObj(chartHeight);

            }
            var templateSrc = "{{#each clgTables}}<option {{#if selectedSnapshot}}selected{{/if}}>{{ClgName}}</option>{{/each}}";
            var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSrc);
            var serializedTablesValues = {
                clgTables: this.collection.toJSON()
            };
            var selectorElement = this.$el.find("select.clgchart-selection");
            selectorElement.html("<option>Choose</option>" + template(serializedTablesValues));
            this.chartingObj.addSeries({
                name: 'clg values',
                data: data,
                shadow: false
            }, false);

            that.chartingObj.setSize(that.getChartWidth(), chartHeight, false);
            this.chartingObj.redraw();
        },
        modifyTableValue: function (clgTableModel) {
            console.log("inside modifyTableValue");
            this.collection.reset(clgTableModel.get("ClgName").models);
        },
        tableModified: function (args) {
            var selectedTerm = $(args.target).val();
            console.log("selectedTerm:" + selectedTerm);
            var that = this;
            this.collection.each(function (clgTableModel) {
                if (selectedTerm === clgTableModel.get("ClgName")) {
                    that.modifyTableValue(clgTableModel);
                }
            });
        },
        initChartObj: function (chartHeight, series) {
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            var chartWidth = this.getChartWidth();
            this.chartingObj = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: this.$el.find(".chart-clg")[0],
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            });

            this.isChartInitialized = true;
        },
        getChartWidth: function () {
            //console.log("inside getChartWidth");
            var chartWidth = 365;

            return chartWidth;
        }
    });

    callSer = function (dispSelector) {
        var test = new Array();
        test = {
            "root": [{
                "Ischart": false,
                "re": {
                    "Name": "Depo"
                },
                "Clg": [{
                    "Name": "james",
                    "Rate": 0.05
                }, {
                    "Name": "Jack",
                    "Rate": 0.55
                }, {
                    "Name": "Edvin",
                    "Rate": 0.95
                }, {
                    "Name": "Mcd",
                    "Rate": 0.21,
                }],
            }]
        };
        var tables = loadFromJson(test.root[0].Clg);
        var clgValueTable = new ClgView({
            collection: tables,
            el: dispSelector,
            showCharts: false
        });

        clgValueTable.render();

    };
</script>
```

Could any one please tell me how to proceed further or give some suggestion in order to accomplish it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After catching select event and getting value, you can try to call point.update / addPoint / setData function and modify data.

Comment: yes, I am trying to do this one in "modifyTableValue" function by using "collection.reset" function...But it is not working..Could you just give me a basic code sample?

Comment: You have to use `Highcharts` methods for this, like Sebastian said.

Comment: i am new to Highcharts. Can anyone provide any sample code to use?